# Find sample points on a path defined by two points

Tags: vba, excel

I have a path defined by two points (lat, long), I want to make a list of points on this path and between two points.

For example, if the two defining points are 100 meters far, I want a list of the points between them each 1 meter away from the other.

Comment: You've been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Comment: sorry about that, I really did figure out the answer just after I submitted the question

Answer (score 0):

1- Calculate distance between the two points
2- Calculate bearing between the two points
3- Divide the distance by the number of samples needed
4- Find each new destination (sample) point by incrementing the distance calculated in step 3

All functions are here

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html